# Is PHP a web Technology or a scripting language?

Tags: php

Its very basic and silly question....

Is PHP a web Technology or a scripting language?

I believe as it is scripting language, but why  other believes it as web technology?

and if its a scripting language then in which web technology does the PHP counts in?

i know it might seem a vague question to some people, but lets face the truth many of us are confused about it..
So geeks please clarify me....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why can't it be both?  If scripting languages are interpreted languages, then PHP is clearly a scripting language.

If a web technology is something used on the net, then PHP is clearly a web technology - it powers many sites on the net.

I see nothing which would prevent PHP from being both a scripting language and a web technology.

Comment: What about PHP frameworks like Laravel? Are these technologies as well?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is web-oriented (the only one) scripting language.
That's why many people confuse it with web technology.

Comment: what do you mean by "the only one" ... PHP can be run via CLI as well.

Comment: Only one? How about JSP?

Comment: Isn't JSP just Java-based web-technology?

Comment: old-style asp is definitely a scripting language for the web.

Comment: Classic ASP is also a scripting one.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's a multi purpose scripting language that was originally made for web development. So it's both.